# Overlays in Tikz giving Errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, only

My tikz figure is working perfectly within beamer. But I need to draw an arrow on slide two. Whenever I insert `\only<2>` or `\onslide<2>` within THIS tikz picture, it gives error:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Example 3.2}
\Large $L = \lbrace w\#w | w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rbrace$ \normalsize
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, node distance = 0.6cm, semithick]
\begin{scope}
\newcounter{prevI}\setcounter{prevI}{0}
\node(n0) at (0,0){};
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1,1,0,0,0,\#,0,1,1,0,0,0,$\sqcup$}{
    \node[right of = n\theprevI,minimum size=0.6cm] (n\i) {\x};
    \stepcounter{prevI}
}
\node[right of= n\theprevI]{$\cdots$};
\end{scope}

%\only<2>{ 
    \draw [->] (0,1) -| (n1); 
%}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

This compiles perfectly fine, even draws the arrow on the current slide correctly. **BUT** when I uncomment the `\only<2>` at the bottom, Latex compiler gives me errors:

```
line 145: Command \c@prevI already defined. \end{frame}
line 95: You need to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to use the Fira fonts
line 14: Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Please use the decoration libraries instead of the snakes library
line 66: Overfull \vbox (50.88618pt too high) detected
line 66: Overfull \vbox (15.63992pt too high) detected
: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! The problem is that if you add a second overlay, the counter will be created again, hence the error. So in order to solve the problem you need to move `\newcounter{prevI}` before the frame. It also turns out that the same effect can cause weird effects with counters, which is why you may want to add `\resetcounteronoverlays{prevI}`, even though it is not yet needed here. Moreover, instead of `\only` I'd recommend using `visible on=` from `overlay-beamer-styles`. For more complicated slides this helps to avoid jumps.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,overlay-beamer-styles}
\newcounter{prevI}%<-moved
\resetcounteronoverlays{prevI}%<-added, not necessary at this point
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example 3.2}
\Large $L = \lbrace w\#w | w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rbrace$ \normalsize
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, node distance = 0.6cm, semithick]
\begin{scope}
\setcounter{prevI}{0}
\node(n0) at (0,0){};
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1,1,0,0,0,\#,0,1,1,0,0,0,$\sqcup$}{
    \node[right of = n\theprevI,minimum size=0.6cm] (n\i) {\x};
    \stepcounter{prevI}
}
\node[right of= n\theprevI]{$\cdots$};
\end{scope}

\draw [->,visible on=<2>] (0,1) -| (n1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. Instead of the `\vspace` you could just increase the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`, and one can trade the counter for a `remember` key.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example 3.2}
\Large $L = \lbrace w\#w | w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rbrace$ \normalsize
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, node distance = 0.6cm, semithick]
\begin{scope}
\node(n0) at (0,0){};
\foreach \x [count=\i,remember=\i as \j (initially 0)] in {0,1,1,0,0,0,\#,0,1,1,0,0,0,$\sqcup$}{
    \node[right of = n\j,minimum size=0.6cm,alias=lastn] (n\i) {\x};
}
\node[right of= lastn]{$\cdots$};
\end{scope}
\draw [->,visible on=<2>] (0,1) -| (n1); 
\path (0,2.5); %instead of \vspace
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is a more elaborate animation.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,overlay-beamer-styles}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentoverlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\newcounter{prevI}%<-moved
\resetcounteronoverlays{prevI}%<-added, not necessary at this point
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example 3.2}
\Large $L = \lbrace w\#w | w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rbrace$ \normalsize
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, node distance = 0.6cm, semithick]
\begin{scope}
\setcounter{prevI}{0}
\node(n0) at (0,0){};
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,1,1,0,0,0,\#,0,1,1,0,0,0,$\sqcup$}{
    \node[right of = n\number\value{prevI},minimum size=0.6cm] (n\i) {
    \ifnum\i<\currentoverlaynumber%
    X
    \else
    \x
    \fi};
    \stepcounter{prevI}
}
\node[right of= n\number\value{prevI}]{$\cdots$};
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\value{prevI}}
{\draw [->,visible on=<\the\numexpr\X+1>] (0,1) -| (n\X); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo... it worked !!! But this will make the local variable accessible everywhere, making it a global variable. To avoid this I had put it inside the frame.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I change the first 0 to an X on the second slide? (I am trying to animate the turing machine behaviour).

Comment: @fakhir Counters are always global. The second solution has no global variable (except that Ti*k*Z makes the node information always global, but this doesn't count).

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat: One issue fixed.. Thank you !!! Now how do I change the first 0 to an X on slide 2? So essentially I am looking to modify a node's text on another slide. Is that possible ?

Comment: @fakhir I added a more elaborate animation at the end. Basically you can play with `\ifnum` to do all sorts of tricks. Especially once you make `\beamer@slideinframe` accessible. (Use with care, though.)

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat: Thank you. This will become very ugly if I intend to place X at random locations. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would use different approach, without of the counter `prevI`. With employing TikZ library `chains` and inserting empty node `n0` in the loop, code become simpler and works as desired:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Example 3.2}
\Large $L = \lbrace w\#w | w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rbrace$ \normalsize
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, semithick, 
node distance = 6mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
                        ]
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {,0,1,1,0,0,0,\#,0,1,1,0,0,0,$\sqcup$, \dots}%
{
    \node[minimum size=6mm, on chain] (n\i) {\x};
}

\only<2>{
    \draw [->] (0,1) -| (n2);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]